# while creating the runbook as draft using azure REST api in python i am facing the error...!

Tags: python, api, rest, azure, azure-automation

I need to create Azure Automation account, and I want to create run book under automation account for auto-scheduling the VM's

### Steps I followed for creating Azure automation account.

1. creating cloud service using API
    https://management.core.windows.net/sdjgsdgj-abcd-2323-98cd-3bd6bcf93702/cloudServices/cloudsername
2. Next step, is I am creating Azure automation account under the created cloud service using above api.
   https://management.core.windows.net/sdjgsdgj-abcd-2323-98cd-3bd6bcf93702/cloudServices/cloudsername/resources/automation/AutomationAccount/testacc2?resourceType=AutomationAccount&detailLevel=Full&resourceProviderNamespace=automation'
3. After that, i want to create runbook under that create automation account for this I am using the below API in Python

```python
import adal
import requests
import json

token_response = adal.acquire_token_with_username_password(
'https://login.windows.net/rapiddirectory.onmicrosoft.com',
'test@xyz.onmicrosoft.com',
'abcd'
)
access_token = token_response.get('accessToken')
create_run_draft = 'https://management.core.windows.net/sdjgsdgj-abcd-2323-98cd-3bd6bcf93702/cloudServices/cloudsername/resources/automation/~/automationAccounts/testacc2/runbooks/write-helloworld/draft?api-version=2014-12-08'

param3 = {
   "tags":{
  "Testing":"show value",
  "Source":"TechNet Script Center"
   },
"properties":{
  "description":"Hello world",
  "runbookType":"Script",
  "logProgress":"false",
  "logVerbose":"false",
  "draft":{
     "draftContentLink":{
        "uri":"https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/The-Hello-World-of-Windows-81b69574/file/111354/1/Write-HelloWorld.ps1",
        "contentVersion":"1.0.0.0",
        "contentHash":{
           "algorithm":"sha256",
           "value":"EqdfsYoVzERQZ3l69N55y1RcYDwkib2+2X+aGUSdr4Q="
        }
     }
  }
}
}
headers2 = {'x-ms-version' : '2013-06-01','Content-Type' : 'application/json',"Authorization": 'Bearer ' + access_token}
output = requests.put(create_run_draft,headers=headers2,data=param3).text
print output
```

I am using Python programming language to achieve this for Azure REST API

I am getting the below error

```
<Error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsazure" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.
org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><Code>InternalError</Code><Message>The server encou
ntered an internal error. Please retry the request.</Message></Error>
```

Please help me out of this problem I am struggling with error

Comment: Hi Rapid, please refer to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt674573.aspx to try the new API for creating a runbook as a draft. Any update, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Please can briefly explain what is the process for creating automation account and how to add runbooks in automation account, how to run the runbooks in specific time. I want to implement through Microsoft REST API's

Answer (score 0):

Could be because you are passing the values of logProgress and logVerbose as strings (`"false"`) instead of as booleans (`false`).

This worked for me:

Create runbook:

`PUT https://management.core.windows.net/90751b51-7cb6-4480-8dbd-e199395b296f/cloudservices/OaaSCS/resources/automation/~/automationAccounts/JoeAutomationAccount/runbooks/testabc?api-version=2014-12-08`

Request body:

`{
  "properties": {
    "logVerbose": false,
    "logProgress": false,
    "runbookType": "Script",
    "draft": {
      "inEdit": false,
      "creationTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00+00:00",
      "lastModifiedTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00+00:00"
    }
  },
  "name": "testabc"
}`

Upload draft content:

`PUT https://management.core.windows.net/90751b51-7cb6-4480-8dbd-e199395b296f/cloudservices/OaaSCS/resources/automation/~/automationAccounts/JoeAutomationAccount/runbooks/testabc/draft/content?api-version=2014-12-08`

Request body:

`workflow testabc {
    "hello"
}`